# Jaxb: local namspacing via the xmlns attribute instead of the element prefix?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm generating some XML with Jaxb that looks pretty good.  Here's a snipit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<ns2:oval_system_characteristics xsi:schemaLocation="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-system-characteristics-5 oval-system-characteristics-schema.xsd http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-common-5 oval-common-schema.xsd http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-system-characteristics-5#esx esx-system-characteristics-schema.xsd" 
xmlns:ns2="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-system-characteristics-5" xmlns="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-common-5" xmlns:ns3="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-system-characteristics-5#esx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

...

```
<ns3:visdkmanagedobject_item id="1">
    <ns3:property>isolation.tools.diskWiper.disable</ns3:property>
    <ns3:value datatype="boolean">true</ns3:value>
</ns3:visdkmanagedobject_item>
```

This is standards compliant XML.  Unfortunately the I'm limited by the constraints of the downstream system, it only accepts XML formatted this way:

```
<visdkmanagedobject_item id="1" xmlns="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-system-characteristics-5#esx">
    <property>isolation.tools.diskWiper.disable</property>
    <value datatype="boolean">true</value>
</visdkmanagedobject_item>
```

Where certain elements are namespaced through the xmlns attribute.
Now for the question, how do I get Jaxb to stop (doing the right thing) namespacing the elements with a prefix and start namespacing the elements with  the xmlns attribute?

Answer (score 2):

You can setup a default namespace by leveraging the `@XmlSchema` annotation at the package level.  This is done by leveraging a `package-info` class (example below):

**com.example.package-info**

```
@XmlSchema(
    namespace = "http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-system-characteristics-5#esx",
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package com.example;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

Answer (score 0):

there are a couple of ways to attack this problem.  it might be as simple as [this](http://www.coderanch.com/t/518707/XML/JAXB-XML-default-namespace), or you may need to take [complete control](http://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/customizing_jaxb) of the namespace prefixes.  (btw, that second xml is not "incorrect", it's just using a default namespace.  it *would* be incorrect, however, for a system to require a specific prefix for the xml).