# Why I can't use xmlns attribute?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, attributes

I have class A:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "A")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class A {
    @XmlAttribute(name = "xmlns")
    private String xmlnsAttr;

    public String getXmlnsAttr() {
        return xmlnsAttr;
    }

    public void setXmlnsAttr(String xmlnsAttr) {
        this.xmlnsAttr = xmlnsAttr;
    }
}
```

If xmlnsAttr has attribute name 'b' (or any other, but not 'xmlns'), it is ok. But if name = "xmlns" I have problem:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#", local:"A"). Expected elements are <{}A>
```

Test:

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    StringReader reader = new StringReader("<A xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#\"></A>");

    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(A.class);

    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
    A a = (A) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
    assert a.getXmlnsAttr() != null;
}
```

Sorry for my bad English. 
See also [Query XDocument with xmlns attribute (namespace)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16018434/query-xdocument-with-xmlns-attribute-namespace)
and 
[Jaxb: local namspacing via the xmlns attribute instead of the element prefix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843511/jaxb-local-namspacing-via-the-xmlns-attribute-instead-of-the-element-prefix)

PS: if I add

```
@XmlSchema(namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#")
package <my package>;
```

I will have assertation problem (a.getXmlnsAttr() is null).

Comment: Using prefix with name space, solves this ` xmlns:prefix=\"`, though you should research why default name space gives you an error.

Comment: @CrazySabbath I should parse element with xmlns without prefix. See https://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core2/, Example 27

Comment: According to w3 specifications you should, which does not mean that jaxb implements it perfectly.